# Index out of range crash where the count is bigger than the index

Tags: swift

I have some pretty well-tested code that never crashed before. Since upgrading to Xcode 15 I'm suddenly getting an `index out of range` crash on some customer devices. It never happens for me locally and I only have the crashdump from TestFlight. I have no idea where this could be coming from, especially since I am checking for bounds. The `text.count > index` check should ensure the index is in range or am I missing anything? My colleague is suggesting a compiler issue. Any idea?

This is part of a larger function, but the relevant part is:

```
if let firstEnum = stateActions.first(where: { $0.type == .enumVar }){
    if let arg = firstEnum.arg,
       arg.count > 2, 
       variableDataDict.keys.contains(firstEnum.endpoint),
       let varData = variableDataDict[firstEnum.endpoint],
       let index = varData.value as? Int, //varData.value is Any?
       let texts = varData.texts, //varData.texts is [String]?
       texts.count > index
    {
        let text = texts[index] // <- This is where the crash is reported
        buttonText += "\n" + text
    }
}
```

Comment: asynchrone issue?

Comment: @Larme In what sense? This part of the code is sync and the datatypes are no reference objects. The closure context should have a valid version of of the array or not?

Comment: Sorry, I meant if there was a threading issue, with another variable accessible the value or modifying it. If you use the debugger, what are the value when it crashes each interesting variables? Are you in a specific thread?

Comment: @Larme How should this happen? Both texts and index are local variables that should hold copies of the values from varData - or am I missing something?

Comment: @Larme I can't reproduce the crash locally. I only get crash reports through TestFlight - and I am wondering what I am missing...

Comment: Since we have no idea what the data is (variableDataDict) it's really hard to troubleshoot this. `text.count > index`, this is always true if index < 0 or the array index might not be continuous or some other wild guess...

Comment: @JoakimDanielson OMG index < 0 - I believe is the right answer here! The data is some large dictionary containing JSON data - and there have been inconsistencies in the past - they might have changed the web service while I was upgrading XCODE! Thank you so much! Sometimes you can't see the obvious!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why it is happening?

Take a look at this example:

```
let allTexts = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
let texts = allTexts[4...]

print(texts.count) // Prints 2
print(texts[0]) // Fatal error: Index out of bounds
```

It's because although the array *contains* two elements, their indices are not as you expected.

```
texts.indices // would be: 4..<6
```

---

###### How to make it behave as I expected originally?

✅ You can convert it to an array to reset the indices like:

```
Array(texts).indices // would be: 0..<2
```

So then the following code would not throw an error:

```
Array(texts)[0] // would be: 4
```

---

#### A better check

Instead of comparing the `count` and the `index`, you can check:

```
if texts.indices.contains(index)
```

This way you can be sure about accessing the `texts[index]` directly

Comment: Interesting!! Did not know that one!
Although I am pretty sure I never slice that array like this (It comes straight out of JSON), I will try using your check! The index apparently is the index out of the original JSON as well...
Any idea why this could come up with XCode 15 and wasn't an issue before?

Comment: I checked... and I believe this isn't the reason for the crash. varData.texts is of type Array<String>? and not Array<String>.Subsequence so the texts.count check should be valid.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson was correct, but still your check would have cought it. Therefore also right answer! Thank you!